# Is this the best way to store this data?

Tags: sqlite, database-design, relational-database

I have a tree-like structure of data stored for a game recorded hourly. I have a tree of folders in the format: Username/Year/Month/date/time.csv

My aim is to replace that by :

[image]

- server gives the server the user was logged into.
- UserExperience will record all skills experience was gained in over the hour (and how much). So an aggregate for the hour.
- This is one I'm really unsure on : UserActivites. This could be variable text of some events that happened over the hour ("I levelled X skill to level Y", "I killed Z many of boss A", "I completed quest B") and many more that are added and removed overtime, so not something I can exactly make a primary-key. I'm not sure what can be done here.

Also not sure how to query statistics of some set of users between 2 dates but that is a separate problem.

Answer (score 1):

So the activity (in *UserActivites*) is always one that relates to a (over the time maybe growing) *Activities* lookup table. The text representation of the activity is in the Activities table and you are just linking to it from your UserActivities table - seems ok so far. You have already a foreign key pointing from *UserActivities.ActivityID* to *Activities.ActivityID* (and the same for Username to UserStatus)?

The datetime is just a point in time - no need to put it into some sort of combined index (as the primary key is). You might index the datetime in the future for a better query performance though.

What *I* would do is:

- throw away the combined primary key on UserActivities
- create a non-meaningful, auto-incrementing integer primary key in the UserActivities table (`ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`)

Things you should consider:

- create an index on Username and another one on ActivityID in UserActivities; it's not necessary, but recommended that child key columns of foreign keys have an index (https://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_indexes)

Your data design looks good that way. You mentioned *"and removed overtime"* concerning the user activities (if I understood correctly). If so I would create a boolean column in UserActivities for **deleted** records. That way you can analyze activities that have been removed. *I* would never delete records once they have been created in the database.

Comment: What I meant by removed overtime is that the game may no longer post those activities for the game. I myself would have no need to remove them :) So, if I understand this right, remove the activities table altogether, and the composite-primary key in UserActivities, but place a foreign key pointing to the composite primary key of UserStatus? this sounds like a good model :) would there be any harm in indexing everything here? I also read auto-incrementing keys are not recommended and to use RowID if not deleting any records

Comment: No, I would say auto-incrementing keys are recommended (they are the RowID in fact). I'm not sure if I really understand the composite primary key of your UserStatus table...

"indexing everything" always comes with a price: every index causes additional load on a database write. So only index if it makes sense and the current model really suffers from a bad performance when you query it.